# How to display double quotations in lstlisting, currently getting error and large space between lines

Tags: listings

I am using following listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
1pragma solidity 0.4.16;
2contract TestContract{
3   string private mystring =”foo”;
4   uint private lastupdated = now;
5   function getString() constant returns    6(string, uint) {
7      return (myStrig, lastUpdated);
8   }
9}
\end{lstlisting}
```

but its not displaying the double quotation in the output. Its generating an error and there is large space between the lines. I want to reduce the space.

The image is given below:

[image: Error Message, No space between lines, No double quotation in output]

The documentclass information is:

```
\documentclass[manuscript,screen]{acmart}
\usepackage{listings}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}


\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\acmYear{2020}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet. Then others can test your code as is. Here we have to guess class and preamble

Comment: That said are those ascii double quotes or some utf8 chars? They should be ascii

Comment: And you should leave line numbering to listings.

Comment: I have added some information. I am following the acm journal format. I have typed the double quotation character from the key board i.e. character " i.e left of "enter key". How can I leave the numbering to listings? please guide me.